# Compare DayTime strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, date, c++11, c++-chrono

If I have a single string storing both Day and Time in the format "mm/dd-hh:mm" how can I create the string of two days ahead?

Comment: Should `"02/28-00:00"` map to `"03/01-00:00"` or `"03/02-00:00"`?  I.e. do you want to assume a leap year or not?

Comment: 03/02:00, February with 28 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Howard Hinnant's [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library.

1. First of all, fix the input string by adding something that could be parsed as a year, and not a leap year (e.g. `"01/"`), so that `date::from_stream` parses the date and time input string into a time point (`tp1`) correctly.
2. Get the date two days ahead of `tp1`, that is, `tp1 + days{2}`.
3. Format the new date back to a string by using `date::format`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/9ETaxGr6T)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <date/date.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>

std::string two_days_ahead(const std::string& dt) {
    auto fixed_dt{std::string{"01/"} + dt};
    std::istringstream iss{fixed_dt};
    date::sys_time<std::chrono::minutes> tp1{};
    date::from_stream(iss, "%y/%m/%d-%H:%M", tp1);
    return date::format("%m/%d-%H:%M", tp1 + date::days{2});
}

int main() {
    std::cout << two_days_ahead("10/30-09:50") << "\n";
}

// Input: "10/30-09:50"
// Output: 11/01-09:50
```

Comment: You could directly format `tp2` with `"%m/%d-%H:%M"` instead of manually computing the resultant fields.

Comment: the output should be the same format of the input data, because after this I have to compare if another string of date and time is before or after the new string just created

Comment: Noted.  With my correction, the output format will be correct: `11/01-09:50`

Comment: Also, as clarified in a comment in the question concerning leap years, `fixed_dt` should contain `"01/"` instead of `"00/"`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Many thanks for all the comments and corrections. I've updated my answer to include them!

Comment: Nice job, upvoted.